# Padding inside <input> shows 2 result in Firefox and other browsers

Tags: html, css, user-interface, firefox

**Check this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fcg48csy/5/) first.**

Here my `<input>` with has a `height of 10px;` has given a `padding of 10px;`, I know it is not a right way of giving style. But still, **it's working perfectly in Chrome, IE and Safari** but it is an another story when it came to **Firefox it crops my `placeholder`**.why.?

I know different browsers have their different rendering methods but can anyone point me the exact reason behind this and is there a way I can solve this **without changing the height, padding or font size**(it should not be less than 14px).?

Comment: Might be appropriate line-height is missing. Browsers do have font rendering issue.

Comment: @AnmolSandal I tried giving them `line-height:10px;` but still no use.

Comment: @weBer  lol, because your font-size is 14,  it must be more, set line-height to 1 or bigger than font size

Comment: Try to add some more line-height by default is 18 you can reduce padding from top and bottom. Lt me know if that worked or share css and code please.

Comment: Your font size is larger than your height. Explain how you think Chrome is coping with that and why you would expect Firefox to behave the same way,

Comment: @Dimash I tried already I give it 18 but still no use.

Comment: I have shared my code in the **jsfiddle** please do check that all.!!

Comment: @weBer, I have updated your code in fiddle let me know if it works fine.

Comment: @AnmolSandal give me your link. it's not updated for me in my link.

Comment: @weBer here it is https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/fcg48csy/7/ :-)

Comment: @weBer aaahhhh sorry, i forgot to mention that it was in my like. Apology

Comment: @AnmolSandal - I know it works if I put the height to `auto` but  
is there a way I can solve this without changing the height and padding.? that is my **Q**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151882/discussion-between-anmol-sandal-and-weber).

Comment: how about reduce the placeholder font size.??

Comment: @PadmaRubhan it should not be less than 14px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if it works for [you](https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/fcg48csy/7/)

```
input {
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: normal;
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 18px;
 height: auto;
}
```

Comment: OP said "without changing the height and padding."

Answer (score -1):

They count height and padding differently, try this.
Use only height or only padding.  Here I add height and only x padding

```
input {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Height is not a solution. Always use appropriate css properties to make it perfect.

Comment: is there a way I can solve this without changing the height and padding.? that is my **Q**

Comment: @weBer No, you can not, and not clear why, size of box will not actually change. If you can add new attributes,  what is problem to change current or rewrite them?